How do I add a GPG signature to an already clearsigned file?
I have a clear-signed file (file.txt.asc) that I would like to add my own signature to. I know that you can create a file signed with multiple signatures by using multiple -u parameters, but how can I achieve this after the file was created?
I'm using 24.04

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

I'm using 24.04.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759313/2072269? Basically just sign the file as-is, so that the second signature is for the original file+the first signature, third signature is for the original file+the first signature+the second signature, etc.?

If not, why not just extract the plain text from the file.txt.asc and sign that?
